# dict_pcre.so missing on debian

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, pcre

I've installed postfix as I normally do, using `apt-get install postfix`, but for some reason it's not including `dict_pcre.so` in the install. Is there something I've overlooked, or rather how and where do I get this missing package to install with my postfix?

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u1

# postconf -m
btree
cidr
environ
fail
hash
internal
memcache
nis
proxy
regexp
sdbm
sqlite
static
tcp
texthash
unix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like PCRE doesn't included by default by Debian maintainer. You have to install it by

```
apt-get install postfix-pcre
```

See: [Debian -- Details of package postfix-pcre in wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/postfix-pcre)

---

[File list of package postfix-pcre in wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/postfix-pcre/filelist)

```
File list of package postfix-pcre in wheezy of architecture amd64

/usr/lib/postfix/dict_pcre.so
/usr/share/doc/postfix-pcre/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/postfix-pcre/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/postfix-pcre/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/postfix-pcre/copyright
```

Comment: Perfect! that's exactly what I needed, thank you :)